# Calculating Frame Independent Acceleration In ActionScript 3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, frame-rate

I have a 2D side scrolling game (made with ActionScript 3) that runs at 60 frames per second. I'm trying to make it frame rate independent so it will run on slower devices.

To do this I create a var called `timeElapsed` by calculating how many milliseconds have passed between each frame and dividing that by 16 (60 fps is about 16ms, I think.) So that at 60 fps the result would be about 1. Then I times any time related vars by this number (e.g `player.x = speed * timeElapsed;`) This is the code:

```
private var oldTime          :Number;
private var defaultFrameRate :uint = 16; // the default frame rate in milliseconds
private var timeElapsed      :Number;

...

var newTime      :Number = getTimer();
var timePassed   :Number = newTime - this.oldTime;

this.timeElapsed = timePassed / this.defaultFrameRate;
this.oldTime     = newTime;
```

The problem is, when I try to apply this in a situation that involves an object that moves faster every frame I get this problem:

This is the code that causes the problem (I've changed it a bit for this example):

```
private var speed        :Number = 100;
private var acceleration :Number =  10;

...

this.speed += (this.acceleration * this.timeElapsed);
this.x     += this.speed * this.timeElapsed;
```

The problem with that is this (not real values, just an example):

```
At 60 FPS:
frame 1: speed = 110; player.x = 110;
frame 2: speed = 120; player.x = 230;
frame 3: speed = 130; player.x = 360;
frame 4: speed = 140; player.x = 500;

At 30 FPS (At half the frame rate but the same ammount of real time):
frame 1: speed = 240; player.x = 240;
frame 2: speed = 280; player.x = 560;
```

As you can see, at 30 frames per second the player is moved further in the same amount of real time. What seems to be the issue is that, at 30fps in frame one, my current code doesn't account for the slight difference in speed between frame one and two at 60fps.
I thought of getting the average value of speed between any two frames at 60fps and using that to calculate a more accurate value when the frame rate changes but I got the feeling wouldn't work correctly in some other situations since at 60fps for example, it would move the player by 115 and not 110 pixels.

Is their any way to accurately simulate an object accelerating in a way that is frame rate independent?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should be multiplying the speed by the elapsed time, since you already account for the elapsed time in the calculation for acceleration:

```
this.speed += (this.acceleration * this.timeElapsed);
this.x     += this.speed;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This was the way I was doing it at first but I realised that at, for example, 30 frames per second, not only would I need to make up for the lost acceleration but I would also need the object to travel twice the distance to make up for the 30 frames worth of lost distance.

Although, I think you might be right in saying what I'm doing now isn't the correct implementation either.

Comment: It will travel twice the distance because `speed` will be doubled.